# override css style on element

Tags: html, css

So I have an element in my html that I need to apply a special style for. 
I can target the elemnt with css but it gets overriden multible other places in css. 
How do I ensure that one style is applied instead of the other?

I tried using !important in my css, but it still won't work.

I am talking about

```
 ul.M1 li.M3 {
    font-size:13px;
 }
```

but this one is not used instead this is used:

```
li.M3 {
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

and it gets overriden a bunch of other places too.

Comment: importent is now important :) , 
change the order in which classes appeared, it may help you

Comment: if possible create a jsFiddle??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

order of precedence in css:

- Inline styles
- Embedded styles
- External styles

and selector precedence is:

- ID selector
- attribute selector
- class selector
- child selector
- adjacent sibling selector
- descendant selector
- type selector

but `!important` has the highest priority and if two or more rules has `!important` then precedence will be as above.

```
ul.M1 li.M3 {
    font-size:13px; !important
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

Correct your spelling and use `!important` instead of `!importent`.

**For Instance,**

```
ul.M1 li.M3 {
    font-size:13px !important; 
 }
```

Declare it at the very last of your stylesheet and link that stylesheet in your page at the very end of `</head>`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Declare it at the very last of your stylesheet and link that stylesheet in your page at the very end of </head> - @IronMonkey

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important`!important behind the rule you want to accomplish.

```
li.M3 {
   font-size: 100px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use !important without issue:

```
 ul.M1 li.M3 {
    font-size:13px !important;
 }
```

But I recommend not doing that. I try to avoid using `!important` at all costs. The reason is that once it is applied, it is very difficult to un-apply it. This can lead to some significant issues with maintenance.

I would recommend leveraging specificity instead to apply your style. Learn to love your browser's developer tools, and use them to identify the style that is being applied, *and* the selector that is applying it.

Then, create a new, slightly more specific selector that will carry more weight. For instance, if you apply an ID to your `ul`, you could leverage that to build a more specific selector that should win out:

```
ul#myID li.M3 {
   font-size:13px !important;
}
```